# How to keep the checkboxes checked even if we move from one component to another or refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, session-storage

I am building a functionality that includes multiple checkboxes. I want them to remain checked until we open a new session of the application. How can I achieve this?
I have this code so far.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-morning-dp9j5?file=/src/App.js

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you will need to store the state somewhere else so it doesn't get wiped out when unmounting the component.

Comment: I tried using sessionStorage but I was not able to check the checkbox in the first place which is not an ideal scenario

Comment: Use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) or formik to hold your form state (checkbox elements should be inside a form element) and copy that state into localstorage on any change. When form is submitted, clear state and storage.